# run bash script from php exec()

Tags: php, linux, bash, exec, iptables

how to run `bash` script from `php` with `sudo`

`index.php` :

```
<?php
$arg;
exec("sudo /var/www/script", $arg);
?>
```

script :

```
!#/bin/bash
echo YOUR ARG IS $1;
sudoers www-data ALL=NOPASSWD /var/www/my 
chmod 755 /var/www/my
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you can't `sudo` it directly like that. So you have to change some configurations in sudoers file.

Run `sudo visudo` in console, add the following line at the end of file

```
nobody ALL = NOPASSWD: /var/www/script
```

**P.S.:** It's a security risk to use your script like that which would sometime perform breach in data security in a great extent so my suggestion is don't call your script like that.